# How do I loop through a XML file with repeating nodes with PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml

I would like to use PHP to loop through an XML file from an API response, to create an array with the XML folder nodes `id` and `name`, sort the array content descending (by id), and echo/return the `name` content.

XML content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<success>
    <document>
        <folder>
            <id>295</id>
            <name>My Folder</name>
            <parent>
                <folder>
                    <id>83</id>
                    <name>Contents</name>
                    <parent>
                        <folder>
                            <id>45</id>
                            <name>Sub Folder</name>
                            <parent>
                                <folder>
                                    <id>21</id>
                                    <name>Root Folder</name>
                                </folder>
                            </parent>
                        </folder>
                    </parent>
                </folder>
            </parent>
        </folder>
    </document>
</success>
```

I tried a few things myself with SimpleXML but keep getting stuck because the XML output has these nested `<parent>` nodes and I am not sure how to handle these, to just get the `id` and `name` nodes.

This is the PHP part I have so far:

```php
<?php

if (file_exists('api_results.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string('api_results.xml');
    
    foreach($xml->document->folder as $folder)
    {
        $folders = array();
        
        foreach($folder as $key => $value)
        {
            $folder[(string)$key] = (string)$value;
        }
        
        $folders[] = $folder;
    }

print_r($folders);
      
} else {
    exit('Failed to open api_results.xml.');
}
```

How can I create an array and just add each id/name node and then sort the array content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath, which allows you to search for a list of the `<folder>` nodes.  Using `//folder` will search at all levels of the document and saves you having to worry about nested `foreach` loops.

You can then use `$folder->id` to fetch the `<id>` element within each `<folder>`.

One thing is that you should be using `simplexml_load_file()` to loads data form a file, the string version is designed to load from a string.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('api_results.xml');

$folders = [];
foreach ($xml->xpath('//folder') as $folder) {
    $folders[] = [(string)$folder->id, (string)$folder->name];
}

print_r($folders);
```

Which for your test document gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 295
            [1] => My Folder
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83
            [1] => Contents
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => Sub Folder
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => Root Folder
        )

)
```